# Calculate: $\int_{2}^{7}\frac{\sqrt{9-x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{9-x}}dx $

Tags: integration

How to calculate following integration?

$$\int_{2}^{7}\frac{\sqrt{9-x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{9-x}}dx $$

Comment: We can make this a little less disgusting by multiplying the integrand by $\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt{9-x}}{\sqrt x-\sqrt{9-x}}$. Note that this does put a removable discontinuity in at $x=4.5$, but it's still integrable. Does it look more approachable after that?

Comment: Idont think so its will work

Comment: I don't know what that sentence means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace $x$ by $9-x$. We then get
$$I = \underbrace{\int_2^7 \dfrac{\sqrt{9-x}}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{9-x}} dx = \int_2^7 \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{9-x}} dx}_{x \to 9-x}$$
Adding both we get that
$$2I = \int_2^7 dx = 5 \implies I = \dfrac52$$

---

In general, if we have
$$I = \int_a^b \dfrac{f(a+b-x)}{f(x) + f(a+b-x)} dx$$ where $f(y) + f(a+b-y)$ doesn't vanish in $[a,b]$ then replacing $x$ by $a+b-x$, we get
$$I = \int_a^b \dfrac{f(a+b-x)}{f(x) + f(a+b-x)} dx = \int_a^b \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(a+b-x)} dx$$
Adding both gives us
$$2I = \int_a^b dx \implies I = \dfrac{b-a}2$$

Comment: Very nice explanation. Let me just note that every time I see a tricky integral question on here, and I read through the top answer I am always impressed by (a) how quickly someone managed to type it all out, (b) the clever use of many integration techniques at once, and (c) that it invariably ends with the name "Marvis".

Comment: @IsaacSolomon Thanks for the compliment.